# pg_dumpall Fails with PostGIS Error

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a large (50+ GB) Postgres cluster that I'm trying to backup on 9.2 to upgrade to 9.4.  The server is CentOS 6.6.

When I run pg_dumpall it gets to about 48GB and then fails with:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.0": No such file or directory
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: SELECT a.attnum, a.attname, a.atttypmod, a.attstattarget, a.attstorage, t.typstorage, a.attnotnull, a.atthasdef, a.attisdropped, a.attlen, a.attalign, a.attislocal, pg_catalog.format_type(t.oid,a.atttypmod) AS atttypname, array_to_string(a.attoptions, ', ') AS attoptions, CASE WHEN a.attcollation <> t.typcollation THEN a.attcollation ELSE 0 END AS attcollation, pg_catalog.array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT pg_catalog.quote_ident(option_name) || ' ' || pg_catalog.quote_literal(option_value) FROM pg_catalog.pg_options_to_table(attfdwoptions) ORDER BY option_name), E',
    ') AS attfdwoptions FROM pg_catalog.pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid WHERE a.attrelid = '18040917'::pg_catalog.oid AND a.attnum > 0::pg_catalog.int2 ORDER BY a.attrelid, a.attnum
```

Here is the output of "select version();":

```
PostgreSQL 9.2.10 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11), 64-bit
```

Here is the result of "SELECT PostGIS_full_version();":

```
POSTGIS="2.1.5 r13152" GEOS="3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.9.2, released 2012/10/08" LIBXML="2.7.6" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" TOPOLOGY RASTER
```

It seems like somewhere something is pointing to PostGIS 2.0 (which is long since gone).

How can I get a full dump so I can upgrade to 9.4?

And more importantly, how can I fix it so I don't keep running into this anytime I upgrade?

Update: This ended up being one old database in the cluster that hadn't been used, and for whatever reason hadn't been updated to later versions of PostGIS.  After deleting them the backup and upgrade went smoothly.

Comment: There are two ways: 1) you reinstall postgis 2) you alter all tables (better make a copy first) , dropping all columns that refer to gis datatypes.

Comment: I used yum to remove PostGIS and reinstall it, but that adds postgis-2.1.  I forced a downgrade to PostGIS 2.0, and then it failed because it didn't have "rtpostgis-2.0".  'yum provides "\*/rtpostgis-2.1.so\*" ' shows that recent versions of PostGIS provide it, but 'yum provides "\*/rtpostgis-2.0.so\*" ' doesn't show any versions that provide "rtpostgis-2.0".

Comment: I ~think~ I have it figured out, but won't be able to try until late tonight (production machine).   I need to downgrade PostGIS  to postgis2_91-2.0.6, which provides that file.  But I'm still confused as to what in my schema is linked specifically to the older version of PostGIS and wasn't fixed by the upgrade.  This seems like something is broken in PostGIS (I'll post on their boards and see what they say).  Thanks

Comment: There was a major upgrade in postgis somewhere ( 2.x, IIRC): point datatypes now have to be expicitely typecasted. For downgrading to an older version you could also try to compile from source(including geos,proj4, etc). (It is not as hard as it seems) First test it on a separate machine ...

Comment: So rather than having to deal with that each time I upgrade, is there a change I can make to my schema that makes the downgrading unnecessary?

Comment: IMHO your first priority would be to get the postgis working again on the 9.2 installation (it is only adding a few .so files + running ldconfig). Then you can dump and (maybe) restore to 9.4. BTW: IIRC there are upgrade howtos in the postgis (source) distributiion.